# WinSCP Plugin for Altap Salamander

Tags: sftp, winscp

Based on these two pages: 
https://www.altap.cz/salamander/help/winscp/ui_login_sftp/
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/salamander#opening_winscp_plugin

I can see there is an WinSCP plugin for Altap Salamander.

But I can't seem to find it.  Do you have to install the plugin? 
Or what keys do you hit.

When I try ALT-F1 or Alt-F2 as mentioned, I see an FTP manager, but nothing for SFTP.

[image]

I looked under plugins manager and don't see anything under SFTP or WinSCP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WinSCP plugin is available for 32-bit version of Altap Salamander only.

Maybe you are using 64-bit version.

Comment: Perfect.  Wish the Total Commander SFTP was also WinSCP driven, I've seen a few issues with it.  I'm actually doing an SFTP/OpenSSH course for Udemy, so showing several different clients and servers.